# Understanding the meaning of logistic regression coefficients

Tags: machine-learning, logistic-regression

I have a binary logistic regression model (0/1), built over binary features. The feature coefficients are usually in the range (-1, 1). After training, can I use the feature coefficients as a proxy for the 'importance' of a feature? If the coefficient is < 0, does that mean the presence of the feature is a negative for the class (i.e., reduces the probability of the output being 1)?

Answer (score 0):

Right; a negative coefficient means that the feature contra-indicates that class.  The magnitude is, indeed, the relative importance.  -1 and +1 are imperatives: all members of the class do not / do have that feature.

Answer (score 0):

You absolutely can. In fact, this idea of important or 'blame' is the main concept behind machine learning algorithms. The coefficients change many times during the training process through gradient descent. How much the weights update by is actually determined by each weight's contribution towards the cost.

That is, the more a weight is to be blamed for a high cost the more extreme the update will be. Therefore, more extreme values (high positives or low negatives) are an indication of how impactful the respective feature is when the model is making its decision.